# Javascript window.open not doing anything

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a button to open a page when clicked using window.open, but it doesn't do anything

```
<input type = "button" value="Two Players" onClick = "window.open(Two.html);">
```

Comment: It would have shown an error that says something like "undefined is not an object", because you're trying to access the `.html` property of `Two` which is not the same as the string `'Two.html'`.

Answer (score 7):

```
<input type = "button" value="Two Players" onclick = "window.open('Two.html');">
```

and not

```
<input type = "button" value="Two Players" onclick = "window.open(Two.html);">
```

**Dont' forget the two : `''` for your path `Two.html`**

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/XqsC5/